# Duogenic quartic rings

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Recall that a commutative, unital ring $R$ of finite rank which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for some $n \geq 1$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module is said to be *monogenic* if there exists an element $\gamma \in R$ such that

$$R = \mathbb{Z}[\gamma] = \text{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left\{1, \gamma, \gamma^2, \cdots, \gamma^{n-1}\right\}.$$

When $\gamma$ is an algebraic integer, then we see that $R \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$, where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$.

We generalize the notion of monogenic rings to *duogenic* rings. We say that $R$ is duogenic ($R$ satisfying the same conditions as above) if $R$ can be expressed as

$$\displaystyle R = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha, \beta], \alpha, \beta \in R.$$

Note that all cubic rings are duogenic; this can be seen at once from the classical result of Delone-Faddeev.

In the quartic case, if $R = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha, \beta]$ then a basis of $R$ necessarily takes the shape $\mathcal{B} = \{1, \alpha, \beta, f(\alpha, \beta)\}$ where $f$ is a polynomial in $\alpha, \beta$ of degree at least two.

How does one classify quartic duogenic rings? For example, monogenic rings are always characterized by monic polynomials, i.e., algebraic integers.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$One large class of duogenic quartic rings is given by pairs $f$, $g$ of quadratic polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ in two variables $x$, $y$, such that when writing $f = \sum_{i,j} f_{i,j} x^i y^j$, we have $$ (f_{2,0}g_{0,2}- f_{0,2} g_{2,0})^2 - ( f_{2,0} g_{1,1} - f_{1,1} g_{2,0})(f_{1,1} g_{0,2}- f_{0,2} g_{1,1}) = \pm 1.$$

In other words, the resultant of the degree $2$ homogeneous parts of $f$ or $g$ is $\pm 1$, meaning $\mathbb Z[x,y]/ (f(x,y), g(x,y))$ is integral over $\mathbb Z$.

There is a $\GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ symmetry acting on $f$ and $g$ and another $\GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ symmetry acting on $x$ and $y$, both preserving the ring.

This includes the monogenic case, as a monogenic ring with polynomial $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ can go to a duogenic ring with polynomials $y-x^2$, $y^2 + ax y + by + cx + d$.

Comment: This is very interesting. Bhargava proved that pairs of integral ternary quadratic forms up to $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \times \text{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence parametrize ALL quartic rings, so it seems this family ought to fit nicely with that picture. Is this in the literature?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Yes, this is the obvious specialization of that to produce duogenic rings. I don't know if this is in the literature.